# Jquery slider widget retrieve value and complete calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery UI's slider and i want to return the results from multiple sliders so I can perform a calculation.

this is what i have so far but I'm struggling to get any results from out side the function.

```
$(function() {
  var x
  $("#slider4").slider({
      value: 1,
      min: 0,
      max: 50,
      step: 5,
      slide: function(event, ui) {
          $("#items").val("$" + ui.value);

      }

  });
  $("#items").val("$" + $("#slider4").slider("value"));

 });
```

Ideally outside the function i would want to add multiple slider results similar to below.

```
var z = x * y;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with scope.

if you have:

```
function foo() {
    var x = 1;
}
```

then `x` can only be accessed inside `foo`.  This is also the case with inline-anonymous functions like you have for the jquery doc ready.

Instead, declare functions that get the value for you, eg:

```
function slider4value() {
    return $("#slider4").slider("value");
}

var z = slider4value() * slider5value();
```

or, more generically:

```
function sliderValue(slider) {
    return $(slider).slider("value");
}

var z = sliderValue("#slider4") * sliderValue("#slider5");
```

An alternative is to use global variables, but this is not recommended in general, eg:

```
<script>
    var x;
    var y;
    $(function() {
        x = 1;
        y = 2;
    }

    function calc() {
        var z = x * y;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for that, that makes sense and has really help. i have implemented the above but I get the error slider4 is not defined

here is my code
 `code
     $(function slider4value() {
         return $("#slider4").slider("value");
     });

     var z = slider4value();
     console.log(z);`